# Incluir ZERO antes dos números em arquivo CSV?

Tags: c#

Preciso incluir ZERO pra completar os digitos do CPF no arquivo csv, porém, se o CPF começa com ZERO é tirado os mesmos e fica apenas os números, ou seja, tem cpf que guarda apenas 9 digitos, pois os dois primeiros não entram na conta...

```
public string CreateCSVFile(List<ExcelColumsData> registers)
{
    List<string> linesList = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in registers)
    {
        linesList.Add(item.Licence + ";" + item.CPF.ToString() + ";" + item.CodeANAC + ";" + item.Plate + ";" + item.FullName + ";" + item.BaseContract + ";" + item.IATACODE);
    }

    string fileName = "G3_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".csv";
    FreePassDataContextDataContext dataContext = new FreePassDataContextDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString);
    var freePassConfigurationsEntity = dataContext.FreePassConfigurations.FirstOrDefault();

    string downloadFolderSFTP = "C:\\ftp\\"; 

    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(downloadFolderSFTP + fileName, linesList, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"));

    return fileName;
}
```

No código aparece como string normalmente, mas já no arquivo CSV não. Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Lembrando que não é usado ponto ou traço no CPF, apenas os números mesmo.

Comment: Quais são os comandos utilizados para a criação do seu arquivo CSV?

Comment: Alterei a postagem colocando o método inteiro.

Comment: Sem analisar muito o seu código, achei estranho o seguinte literal: `";'"` na linha 6 (`linesList.Add`) porque não há nenhum apóstrofo final que sirva como delimitador

Comment: Isso foi um teste que fiz, desconsidere, nesse caso ele inclui o apostrofo no começo e imprime os 0 porém, não deveria ter o apostrofo, desculpe meu descuido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar da seguinte forma:

```
Convert.ToUInt64(item.CPF.ToString()).ToString(@"000\.000\.000\-00")
```

Isto força o CPF a passar por uma máscara especificada no segundo `ToString()`.

---

EDIT

Para apenas números, use:

```
String.Format("{0:00000000000}", item.CPF);
```

Estou supondo que CPF é numérico.

Comment: Seria útil, mas no meu caso, não posso usar máscara, apenas números, pois o sistema que lê esse campo, q é de terceiros recebe o CPF apenas por número.

Comment: @EwertonMelo Editei a resposta.

Comment: Então, ainda assim no CSV ele não coloca os números zero na frente...

Comment: @EwertonMelo Editei novamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo. Sua resposta foi de grande ajuda e resolveu o problema. Obrigado mesmo.